# Issue in sending mails with long attachments using EWS

Tags: android, sendmail, email-attachments, exchangewebservices

I am using **EWS** for sending mails to Exchange Server. I am able to send mails with no attachment. When I add any attachment it is failing and giving this error:

```
04-09 13:05:56.157: E/EWSJava!!!(26633): >>>> SimpleServiceRequestBase.internalExecute()
Exception An element node 'm:CreateAttachmentResponse' of the type START_ELEMENT was
expected, but node '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Fault'
of type START_ELEMENT was found.
```

I can see that mail is getting saved in drafts (no attachments in drafts).

My code is:

```
EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(acct.ewsService);
            message.getToRecipients().add(sRecipients);
            message.setSubject(sSubject);
            message.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText(sBody));
            if (fAttachments != null) {
                for (File f : fAttachments) {
                    Log.i("MailSender", "SendSMTPMail() attaching: " + f.getPath());
                    message.getAttachments().addFileAttachment(f.getPath());
                }
            }

            Log.i("MailSender", "SendMail: pre-message.send()");
            message.send();
            Log.i("MailSender", "SendMail: post-message.send()");
```

EDIT:

The same code is working when I try to send files of small size. But its failing for bigger size attachments like images.

Comment: `message.Attachments` should be list of `File/AttachmentType` objects not path to the file (`String`)...

Comment: addFileAttachment creates  File/AttachmentType from the filename and adds that to message.attachments.

Comment: so tell us which java EWS client classes implementation are you using ... i've check C# version and i'm sure that you have to use `FileAttachmentType attach1 = FileAttachmentType();`

Comment: i agree with your first comment . message attachments are of type FileAttachment . And .message.getAttachments().addFileAttachment(f.getPath()); firsat converts the filename string to fileattachment type and then add this to messag.attachments . So it is the same as what you have suggested .